# AngularJS - how to style md-select dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, md-select

I am new to "angularjs".

I need to give border to the dropdown and set font size of the contents of the dropdown. I tried to style in the following manner, but it doesn't work -

```
<md-input-container style="font-size:11px;font-family:verdana;border-width:2px;border-color:darkgray">
  <md-select ng-model="anfcntrl.selbndlegalentities" multiple="">
    <md-option ng-value="legalentity.name" ng-repeat="legalentity in anfcntrl.bndlegalentities"
    style="font-size:11px;font-family:verdana;border-width:2px;border-color:darkgray">{{legalentity.name}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Question: Is there a way to give border to the dropdown and set font size of the dropdown items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example applying green border:

```
md-select-menu md-content md-option {
     border:1px solid green;
     font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Using this style I was able to border the contents of the md-select but the font size remain unchanged. Is there any other way to set the font size of the contents?
Additonally, I was able to set border and font size of the "md-select" itself using style - md-select {border:2px solid gray; font-size:12px; font-family:verdana;}

Comment: yes for content you can do: 

 md-select-menu md-content {
    background-color: blue;
}

Comment: md-select-menu md-content { background-color: blue; } works. But why I try 
md-select-menu md-content { font-size: 8px; } the style doesn't work.

Comment: check here, I applied background and size (check css section last css): https://codepen.io/tranquillity/pen/WNbyXQY